# Find Control Deep Inside LoginView

Tags: c#, asp.net, findcontrol

I have a login view control that I can find with findcontrol. Inside it is LoggedInTemplate->ul->li->ul->li->a. How can I find a? Here is sample code:

> ```
>    <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled" ID="a">
>           <LoggedInTemplate>
>                  <ul class="nav navbar-centered navbar-nav" id="second-menu" role="menu" >
>                      <li class="dropdown"><a runat="server" href="" class="dropdown-toggle" >AB</span></a>
>                         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
>                             <li><a runat="server" id="link">Link</a></li>
> ```

This works:

```
LoginView a = (LoginView)this.Master.FindControl("a");
```

But this doesn't:

```
HyperLink dashboardLink = (HyperLink)a.FindControl("link");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [MSDN page of FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> This method will find a control only if the control is directly
>   contained by the specified container; that is, the method does not
>   search throughout a hierarchy of controls within controls. For
>   information about how to find a control when you do not know its
>   immediate container, see How to: Access Server Controls by ID.

So you have to write your own recursive find method:

```
private Control FindControlRecursive(Control rootControl, string controlID)
{
    if (rootControl.ID == controlID) return rootControl;

    foreach (Control controlToSearch in rootControl.Controls)
    {
        Control controlToReturn = 
            FindControlRecursive(controlToSearch, controlID);
        if (controlToReturn != null) return controlToReturn;
    }
   return null;
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```
LoginView a = (LoginView)this.Master.FindControl("a");
HyperLink dashboardLink = (HyperLink)FindControlRecursive(a,"link");
```

or simply:

```
HyperLink dashboardLink = (HyperLink)FindControlRecursive(this.Master,"link");
```

But for that to work, you will have to use

```
<a runat="server" ID="link">Link</a>
```

as "ID" is case-sensitive, as far as I  know.

**Edit:**
According to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y81z8326%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can access that control by simply using it's name (ID).

> When a control is not inside a naming container, you can get a
>   reference to it by using the control's ID.

The article has sample code too.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I used the function as: HyperLink dashboardLink = (HyperLink)FindControlRecursive((LoginView)this.Master.FindControl("a"), "link"); but it returns null.

Comment: I am using this code in Onloggedin event. Could that be an issue that control has not been formed?

Comment: Most probably this could be the source of your problem. I guess - but this is really a guess - that when you recieve the OnLoggedIn callback the control is still displaying the AnonymousTemplate. But this sounds like a different question :)

Comment: Yup! That's the real problem! I put same code isnide anonymous template and I was able to get the control. Thanks for all your help! I appreciate it. One change I had to make was to change Hyperlink to HtmlAnchor type.